# "Stride" meaning in This context

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of *strode* in the following context?
If you define it as *[to move with or as if with long steps](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stride)* it doesn't  make any sense. I looked every possible definition for *stride* in dictionaries but none of them makes any sense here!

> My father’s family came from Moravia. There the Jewish communities
>   lived in small country villages on friendly terms with the peasants
>   and the petty bourgeoisie. They were entirely free both of the sense
>   of inferiority and of the smooth pushing impatience of the Galician or
>   Eastern Jews. Strong and powerful, owing to their life in the country,
>   they went their way quietly and surely, as the peasants of their
>   homeland strode over the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stride](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stride) means "to walk with long steps, as with vigor, haste, impatience, or arrogance."

So, the meaning is not only literal, but includes the passion or behaviour. As I understand, in "peasants of their homeland strode over the fields" the "stride" means walking "up and down" or "all over" the fields in a kind of confident or overconfident manner.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/stride) gives this explanation of "stride:"

> Walk with long, decisive steps in a specified direction.

...and gives this example:

> We are striding confidently towards the future.

Comment: Well I don't think so. The era (18th century) and the place which the story happens in indicates that those peasents were in fact farmers. And assuming this, and even without it we can say that by "fields" author means their farms. With that said I can't accept that it LITERALLY means walking with long steps!

Comment: @iAMR77, this is exactly what I said. It is an observer (in this case the author of the text) who can say that someone strode, meaning, walking in a sort of confident manner, not necessary literally with long steps. And yes, fields can be farms.

Comment: I just saw your edited answer and it's added part seems somehow acceptable. Can you just give a source that it says strive can mean walking with confidence rather than struggle/hurry/great effort? Thank you!

Comment: @iAMR77  OK, I did.......